# Find and examine graph

Tags: calculus, functions, relations

I need some help with this task:

Given the function $f: \{1,2,3\} \to \mathbf{N}, f (1) = 1, f (2) = 3, f (3) = 2$.

a) Find the graph $\operatorname{graph}(f)$ of $f$.

b) By $f$, a relation is given on the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$. Examine these for reflexivity, symmetry, antisymmetry, and transitivity.

As far I as I understand it by talking about graph we are not talking about pictures visualising the function f but rather about the set

$$\operatorname{graph}(f):= \{(x,y) \in A \times B : y=f(x)\}$$

But how do I continue from that? Like so:

$$A = \{1,2,3\} \text{ and } B = \mathbf{N}$$

So $\operatorname{graph}(f) = \{(x,y) \in A \times B: y=f(x)\}$? It can't be that simple, right?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: $G(f)=\{(x,f(x)) : x \in A\}$ is equivalent to your definition. So what are all the possible pairs?

Comment: Check my edit and see [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for advice going forward.

Comment: Aren't the pairs given in the second line? (1,1), (2,3), (3,2)

Comment: so a) would be graph(f):={(1,1), (2,3), (3,2)}

Can you also give me a tip with b)? :)

Comment: @kiaora.  Yes, a is that simple and the graph is the relation;  b is simply a matter of applying the definitions to the tedium of checking that tiny relation against them.